# root partition is full when trying to open big files

Tags: ubuntu, partition

I have big tar.gz and .rar files.

when i try to open them (even to amounted partition with over 500G) my root partition is consumed, i'm guessing it's something to do with temp files but i have no idea how to open it.

Here's my `df -h` output:

```
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  4.7G  2.9G  63% /
udev            3.7G  8.0K  3.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.5G  176K  1.5G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /run/shm
/dev/xvdf       493G  9.1G  459G   2% /mnt/att
s3fs            256T     0  256T   0% /mnt/buckets3
```

Comment: How big are the files? What command are you using for extraction?

Comment: files are 6G and i'm doing standard gzip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that `tar` uses the `/tmp` directory for intermediate files.  You have a couple of options.

One is to mount `/tmp` to a larger disk in your `fstab`.  But that's a bit overkill.

Instead, you can set the `$TMPDIR` environment variable.  If present, `tar` will use that instead of `/tmp`.

Comment: "I believe that tar uses the /tmp directory for intermediate files." -- Citation Needed, as the Wikipedeans say.  I see no activity in `/tmp` via `strace` on a test decompress I just ran.